# CodeIgniter: active record SET taking second field name as string value instead of field name

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, set, updates

Please see below simple code. In SET command it should take both parameters as field name instead it is taking the second parameter as a string value

```
$var = '2020-11-01 01:33:51';
        $var1 = id;
    $this->db->set('location', call_type);
    $this->db->where('call_date', $var);
    if($this->db->update('phone_acc')) {

            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
```

these statements creating this query:

```
     UPDATE `phone_acc` SET `location` = 'call_type' WHERE `call_date` = '2020-11-01 01:33:51'
```

call_type is field name not string value. it should read 'call_type' as a field name. What should I do any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

To make the other variable as Field name we need to add a flag 'false' in the statement just like this;

```
 $this->db->set('location', 'call_type', false);
```